# Missing Keyword when using Case in Where clause

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using `case` in `where` clause but getting error: `missing keyword`

**SQL:**

```
SELECT *
FROM tmp t
WHERE
    CASE :p_flag WHEN 'Y'
                 THEN t.call_destination NOT IN ('Premium', 'Satellite')
                 ELSE t.call_destination LIKE call_destination
    END;
```

Comment: `ELSE t.call_destination LIKE call_destination` ... this makes no sense.  What is the actual else logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predicate of a `CASE` expression has to be a single value, not another expression.  If I read your `WHERE` clause correctly, you ought to be able to rephrase your query as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM tmp t
WHERE
    (:p_flag = 'Y' AND t.call_destination NOT IN ('Premium','Satellite')) OR
    (:p_flag <> 'Y' AND t.call_destination LIKE call_destination);
--                                               ^^^ not sure about this
```

I have highlighted a `LIKE` comparison you are making which does not seem to make sense because it would always return true.

Comment: I want exclude 'Premium', Satellite when p_flag is 'Y'.

Comment: I don't see a problem with my code.  Perhaps you copied it wrongly.

Comment: `like` without a wildcard is just an equality operator.

Comment: @APC Um...I know that.  This is why I am questioning the presence of `col = col` in the query.

Comment: @Tim - There's two potential issues here. One is the scoping issue: perhaps the OP has a local variable called `call_destination` and doesn't realise that the table column namespace overrides the block namespace. The other issue is whether that LIKE does what the OP thinks it does. If there's a local variable in play perhaps it might.